# Cannot remove wrong autocorrect/predicitve text language

Tags: ios, autocorrect, auto-complete

I want my iPhone keyboard's autocorrect and predictive text to be English only, but it somehow it is set to both English *and* French at the same time.  For example if I type "tress" then it shows "très" as a prediction.  If I then press space it autocorrects to "très".

French is not selected in my keyboard settings (Settings -> General -> Keyboard) nor in my dictionary settings (Settings -> General -> Dictionary).  These are the two places that one needs to change according to online resources.

Answer (score 1):

When I removed "French" from "Settings -> General -> Language & Region -> Other languages" then the problem disappeared.